# Derivative of a monotone function that has a finite limit as x goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an infinitely differentiable, monotone function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L \neq \infty$.

 Is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ ? I couldn't prove it, nor exhibit a counter example. 

 Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is essentially whether an integrable function must satisfy $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 0$. Here, we additionally require $g$ to be positive, and smooth [$g$ shall be $f'$]. The answer is no.

Construct a positive integrable function that has narrow high peaks say at the integers. We can even choose it unbounded. If the width of the peaks decreases fast enough, the function remains integrable. You can make that smooth (for example by convolution with a compactly supported mollifier). Let $f$ be the integral of that function. Then $f$ is monotone (strictly, if we constructed the derivative strictly positive), has finite limit at $+\infty$, but $f'$ may even be unbounded.

Comment: hmm two completely different answers to the same question!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is true  if (Edit, as pointed out by Daniel Fischer) the limit of $f'(x)$ exists as $x \rightarrow \infty$ (which, as pointed out, may not); otherwise, apply the MVT repeatedly,e.g., in intervals $[n,n+1]$ and show that  $$Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)=\Sigma [f(n+1)-f(n)]=\Sigma_{c_n in [n,n+1]} f'(c_n)$$ , grows without bound (you can turn the sum into a telescoping sum where the terms cancel out) unless $f'(x) \rightarrow 0$, i.e., the sum of the differences is not Cauchy. Daniel Fischer gave a counterexample where $f'(x)$ does not exist as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: It's not true. $f'$ can have high peaks. The _average_ of $f'$ over intervals of fixed length must tend to $0$.

Comment: But for the average of f' to tend to $0$ , f' must become negative, to counter the value at the peaks.

Comment: No, it must just be very small. Let $I_n = [n,n+2^{-n}]$, and consider $$g(x) = e^{-x^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \chi_{I_n}(x).$$ That's strictly positive, unbounded for $x \to \infty$, and has a finite integral. (Of course it's not smooth; mollify it to get it smooth.)

Comment: But what's wrong with my argument about telescoping $f(n+1)-f(n)=\Sigma f'(c_n)$ , where $f'(c_n) \rightarrow a \neq 0$ ? How can that sum converge, if the $n$-th term does not go to $0$?

Comment: That shows that $f'$ must have some values in the interval $[n,n+1]$ where it is small. Or, in other words, that the average of $f'$ on $[n,n+1]$ must tend to $0$ (and so fast that it has a finite sum). One can still have $f'$ large on **small** subintervals. **If** $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists at all, it must be $0$. But the limit need not exist.

Comment: This answer is mistaken: it only shows that in every interval $[n, n+1]$ there exists some $c_n$ such that $f'(c_n) \to 0$. This doesn't imply that $f'(x) \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$, though.