# Convergence of solutions for time to infinity in a 1D autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a constant $a > 0$, show that for every $y_0 > 0$ the solution of an initial value problem
$$ \dot{y} = ay - y^5, \qquad y(0) = y_0 $$
satisfies
$$ y_{\infty} := \lim_{t \to \infty} y(t) = \sqrt[4]{a} $$
**Note:** It's easy to see that $y(t)$ is either constant or strictly monotonous and bounded. We would be done, if one could prove
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} y'(t) = 0 $$
as that would yield
$$ 0 = \lim_{t \to \infty} y'(t) = ay_{\infty} - (y_{\infty})^5 $$
but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621465/derivative-of-a-monotone-function-that-has-a-finite-limit-as-x-goes-to-infinity) let's me doubt that this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solving an autonomous differential equation is not needed to determine the asymptotic behaviour of its solutions, a phase diagram suffices.

Here, $\dot y=F(y)$ where $F:x\mapsto ax-x^5$ hence, on $x\gt0$:

- $F(x)\gt0$ for every $x$ in $(0,\sqrt[4]{a})$
- $F(\sqrt[4]{a})=0$
- $F(x)\lt0$ for every $x$ in $(\sqrt[4]{a},+\infty)$

This alone suffices to show that $y(t)\to\sqrt[4]{a}$ when $t\to+\infty$, for every starting point $y(0)\gt0$ (*increasingly* if $y(0)\lt\sqrt[4]{a}$, *constantly* if $y(0)=\sqrt[4]{a}$, and *decreasingly* if $y(0)\gt\sqrt[4]{a}$).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It is Bernoulli differential equation, so we can reduce it to linear equation and solve.

Comment: Indeed ... can I do that also, if the IVP is $\dot{y} = y(y-2)e^{\cos(x)}$?

Comment: @arney I am afraid that it is much more difficult problem.