# The limit of derivative when the function is monotone increasing and converges

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f(x)\in C^{1}$ is monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$ exists. Is it correct that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{df}{dx}(x)=0$? I think if the limit of the derivative exists, then the limit must be zero. But what if this condition is not given? Is there any counter-example?

Comment: I guess you mean that "$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$ exists and is finite" ?

Comment: Look at Daniel Fischer's answer over at [Derivative of a monotone function that has a finite limit as x goes to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621465/derivative-of-a-monotone-function-that-has-a-finite-limit-as-x-goes-to-infinity). Basically, use Daniel's hint to construct a non-negative function $g$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)dx$ exists, and such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ doesn't exist. Then, consider $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x g(x)dx$, and prove that $f \in C^1$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists, $f$ is monotone, but $f' = g$ doesn't have a limit by choice

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Consider $1-e^{-\lfloor x \rfloor}$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and replace the discontinuities by sharp linear interpolations at each integer, preventing convergence of $f'$. Mollify if necessary to ensure $C^1$.